# Mono won't run with script or sudo

Tags: linux, centos, mono-framework

Whenever I try run a program like this "sudo mono Program.exe" or from a bash script. 
I get the error: `mono: command not found`.

I am running a VPS on CentOS 6 x64 bit.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, `mono` is not in your PATH. How did you install it?

Answer (score 2):

Try the command

```
which mono
```

and see which path is returned. I'm not sure on how Mono is installed, but it's possible that you could be running the executable from your *home* directory, instead of somewhere like '/usr/bin'.

Try creating a new temporary user and executing mono then and see if you get the same error. It seems likely that the program isn't in a location that is included in your Path variable, so it's possible that it didn't install correctly and/or you or the installer didn't move the program to /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin

Comment: Ran the which command. Received this: `/usr/local/bin/mono`

Comment: Change the path from /usr/local/bin/mono to /usr/bin/mono using the above answer. Here's the actual command for anyone else: `mv /usr/local/bin/mono /usr/bin/mono` Thanks very much Joe! :D

Comment: Please do not do that with mv. If you later upgrade then you will have an old binary in /usr/bin and a newer one in /usr/local/bin/. Creating a softlink is a much better idea (though not the proper solution either).

Answer (score 0):

You are running `sudo mono Program.exe`. Lets analyse this:

## Cause:

As a **user** you have a path. You type 'sudo (something) and your shell find the sudo binary in your path and starts it.

Sudo causes you yo switch from your **user** to **uid 0 (root)** and the path which is set for this root user.

The latter path can be difference. In which case you get the 'file not found'.

## Solution:

Either specify the full path (e.g. `sudo /usr/local/bin/mono Program.exe`) or add /usr/local/bin to the path for root.